# Ubuntu 16.04: appstreamcli error while get-update

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, appstream

I am trying to enable WiFi. I tried `sudo apt-get update`. But I am getting this error:

```
The AppStream system cache was updated, but some errors were detected, which might lead to missing metadata. Refer to the verbose log for more information.
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

How can I complete `sudo apt-get update` and enable Wifi in Ubuntu-16.04?

Comment: While upgrading packages via APT may possibly be the start of the process to enable your wifi, it's likely that you'll have to do more than that. Please review this [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](//askubuntu.com/q/425155) and post a new question about your wifi

Comment: The problem is tracked in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1780442

Answer (score 11):

I have had the same problem and the problem was that there was (in my case) an inappropriately escaped character in file `/var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml` in line 265 which broke the xml, hence the error. In line `<checksum filename="Firmware_SF30&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat" target="content" type="sha1">3ef2bdee8aca2a45b9f53b4d4cce9722523f57f8</checksum>` the `&` symbol must be encoded `&amp;` for this to be a valid xml.

Comment: Unfortunately the file reverts to the original &-containing string when fwupdmgr refreshes.

Comment: yeah.. didn't think about that.

Comment: Thanks. I explained my learning and implementing your solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1644498/comments/56).  In short, need to open `/var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml` with either `sudo gedit` or `sudo nano` and goto line 256 and change the `&` symbol to `&amp;`, and save the file. During `sudo apt update`, the error will disappear. My system is using  `libappstream4` package.

Answer (score 5):

A similar bug was reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1583845)

[This answer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712/comments/24) suggested the below in order to solve it (a few people said that it helped them):

> Removing `/usr/bin/appstreamcli` is fine if you install the fixed package afterwards.
>
> To install this manually, please do (for amd64, adjust URLs for other architectures):
>
> ```
> cd /tmp && mkdir asfix
> cd asfix
> wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
> wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libappstream3_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
> sudo dpkg -i *.deb
> ```

Comment: not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not backported to xenial, one can *upgrade `libappstream-glib8` to the version in bionic* and set up to receive upgrades for this package (but not the rest) from bionic.

### Procedure

If you find yourself in one of the cases marked ABORT, just undo all the steps you did so far and run `sudo apt update` at the end (I don't expect that to happen though, they are just there as a safeguard).

1. save a file called (say) `future.list` in dir `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (you'll need sudo) with the following content:

   ```
   deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic main
   deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic-updates main
   deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt bionic-security main
   ```
2. save a file called (say) `future.pref` in dir `/etc/apt/preferences.d` (you'll need sudo again) with the following content:

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release a=bionic*
   Pin-Priority: 50
   ```
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `apt list -u` and confirm it returns *only* "Listing... Done". If it returns more stuff, ABORT (see above).
5. `sudo apt install -assume-no -t=bionic libappstream-glib8`. If, at this stage, apt claims that more is needed to satisfy dependencies than just replacing the old version with the new one, ABORT (see above).
6. `sudo mv /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml ~/fwupd.xml.bck`
7. restart (I found this was required, probably to load the new shared library version, maybe restart some service)
8. `sudo fwupdmgr refresh`
9. `sudo appstreamcli refresh`