# E: Problem executing scripts APT Update::Post-Invoke-Success error during apt-get update

Tags: apt, appstream

I cannot install any package.
It seems the command `apt-get update` must be run
but it throws some errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:2 http://ve.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://ve.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://ve.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Fetched 102 kB in 23s (4337 B/s)                                               
*** Error in `appstreamcli': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000210f4b0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fac8d8317e5]
[...]
Aborted (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 
 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; 
 then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

[Full terminal output.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4gb2dfdpIGeamJWam5Jb0o0OHM)

Comment: Related bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=822317

Comment: Maybe this problem has something to do with Python (version? home folder? I don't know). I explain: I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 20, but the answers here didn't work for me. However, the problem disappeared when I realized that I had changed the symbolic link `/usr/bin/python3` to `/usr/bin/ph3` (yeah, laziness...) a couple of minutes before the error started to show up. When I put it back to `\usr\bin\python3` both the `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` worked well. Maybe some of the programs that are been updated/upgraded need Python. Please, check this out.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Currently having exactly the same error within docker image ubuntu:latest (sha256:18b083992355354958fd861c9f89b393f34d27442c07fa7492a5dbbd516b1c9a). Interesting how this error keeps coming back over the years!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This worked for me
(From here, https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=6174.0):

```
sudo apt-get purge libappstream3
```

Comment: What about the side effects? What caused this issue?

Comment: @EdParadox This happened to me yesterday when updating the software in Ubuntu 16.04 immediately after installing it in VirtualBox with the command `sudo apt upgrade`. This answer worked for me. I was getting many other Apport error notifications at the same time. After updating Oracle VirtualBox and Oracle VirtualBox Extension Pack to the latest version these errors disappeared. I checked in `/var/crash/` and verified that all of these errors were related to appstream which has libappstream3 as a dependency.

Comment: @EdParadox The cause? In my case, the error just happened with no apparent reason, when running `sudo apt-get update` command in Terminal. The side effect? Nothing apparent besides these packages `appstream gnome-software libappstream3` being removed.

Comment: I also had this issue on a fresh install of XUbuntu on VirtualBox. Have no idea why this happens, maybe it has something to do with the virtualisation. But the purge fixed it.

Comment: @Lion Just did a completely fresh install of XUbuntu 16.04 here on real hardware, I got it right away; I've never had this happen before on any other Linux distro; I'd take a guess and say that there might be something wrong with the installer.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: This really saved my a**. Thanks. It's strange that one dumb package would completely fubar an entire fresh install.

Comment: It works on ubuntu-desktop 16.04 LTS OEM.

Answer (score 67):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream3
```

can fix it.

Comment: this fixed this error for me.

Comment: I ran `apt install --reinstall libappstream*`

Comment: Way better solution than the accepted answer, it prevents extra packages from being removed as well (at least on KDE).

Comment: I get an error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 code : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.26) but 2:3.21-1ubuntu4 is to be installed

Comment: If this works it would be better, agreed. As I recall.. I tried it but got some dependency error.

Comment: August 2019 with Ubuntu 18.04, `sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream4` and this problem that's frustrated me for months now seems to be gone!

Answer (score 8):

I came from [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051536/appstreamcli-appstream-system-cache-was-updated-but-problems-were-found-metad?noredirect=1&lq=1) and was redirected here, over there I cannot answer but this is actually an answer for that page. Since I had the same issue (at least same as one of the related issues, but hey I did not relate them so sorry if it is not right solution for you ) and found it quite difficult to find the right information, but in the end succeeded, I thought why not share it here. It took me 2 days evening hours to put the pieces together but this is what I did, hope it helps some of you.

I followed this procedure to clean the mess, made a backup first, just in case.

```
sudo apt install appstream/xenial-backports
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
sudo rm /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream4
sudo appstreamcli refresh --force
sudo reboot
```

Not sure if the reboot is necessary but after reboot I did:

```
sudo appstreamcli refresh --force
```

and had no more errors.

Comment: For me that did the trick - removing `fwupd.xml` and re-installing `libappstream4`. Thanks!

Comment: B4 your procedure, I backed up `fwupd.xml` and `50appstream`. After your procedure, the errors disappeared after `sudo apt update` ( tested for a few reboots). I reinserted  `50appstream` to original location, ran `sudo appstreamcli refresh --force` followed by  `sudo apt update`; no error msg. After reinserting  `fwupd.xml` and do refresh --force and update commands, this error appeared `AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml`.  So `fwupd.xml` caused error. The symbol `&` in line 265 is the likely cause?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1644498 A fix was released in 2017/01 but in 2018/07 this same issue reappears. Think the previous bug fix is no longer working for current error? Seems to be an up trend of this error... Hope a new solution can be found.

Comment: I concluded the files `fwupd.xml` and `50appstream` should not be removed.   They have a purpose. I have posted my solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1644498/comments/56). After fixing the typo in `fwupd.xml`, everything works again.

Comment: @Sun Bear I had this exact same problem and your solution worked for me. Thanks

Comment: This is the only thing that helped me upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue after upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS.  My initial error message was:

```
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
```

Here is what I did to fix it:

```
$ sudo rm /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
$ sudo appstreamcli refresh --force
```

That resulted in this terminal message:

```
AppStream cache update completed successfully.
```

Then, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, purging, or re-installing didn't help.

The removal of the apt.conf.d entry did however solve the issue for me.

```
Friday 25 August  22:17:45 AEST 2017
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial
```

I ran the following commands to get rid of the error:

```
sudo apt-get purge libappstream2
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

Answer (score 1):

For having this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for XXX:           
...

AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

$ sudo appstreamcli --version
AppStream CLI tool version: 0.10.6

$ sudo appstreamcli refresh-cache --force --verbose
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Added /usr/share/app-info/xmls to metadata search path.
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Added /var/lib/app-info/yaml to metadata search path.
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Added /var/cache/app-info/xmls to metadata search path.
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Refreshing AppStream cache
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Searching for data in: /usr/share/app-info/xmls
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Searching for data in: /var/cache/app-info/xmls
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Searching for data in: /var/lib/app-info/yaml
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Reading: /usr/share/app-info/xmls/org.freedesktop.fwupd.xml
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: Reading: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
** (appstreamcli:15334): DEBUG: WARNING: Could not parse XML data: Entity: line 265: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'
        <checksum filename="Firmware_SF30&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat" target="content" t
                                                            ^
...
```

The fix is:

```
$ sudo -i

# cd /var/cache/app-info/xmls/

# ls -l
total 236
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 jul 27 09:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 aug 31  2017 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233177 jun 29 16:02 fwupd.xml

# sed < fwupd.xml  -rne 's/Firmware_SF30\&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat/Firmware_SF30\&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat/gp'
        <checksum filename="Firmware_SF30&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat" target="content" type="sha1">3ef2bdee8aca2a45b9f53b4d4cce9722523f57f8</checksum>

# sed fwupd.xml -i_BACKUP -re 's/Firmware_SF30\&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat/Firmware_SF30\&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat/gp'

# ls -l
total 464
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 jul 27 09:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 aug 31  2017 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233328 jul 27 09:57 fwupd.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 233177 jun 29 16:02 fwupd.xml_BACKUP

# rm fwupd.xml_BACKUP

# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
...
Fetched 491 kB in 0s (715 kB/s)                    
Reading package lists... Done

# exit
logout

$
```

Note:
https://github.com/hughsie/lvfs-website/issues/33

Comment: Answer origin: https://askubuntu.com/a/1053018/28943 ... Original QUESTION (NOTE: NOT A DUPLICATE, YOU'RE TOO QUICK ON THAT!): https://askubuntu.com/q/1051536/289138

Comment: It's worth noting that it's just a temporary solution.  To fix it properly it might be enough to just wait for a fix to this bug to be released: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1780442
Also the original answer seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution in 18.04.1 is to install [appstream](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/appstream) and [libappstream4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/libappstream4) manually from the Cosmic repos; pick your architecture and a mirror, download, install with `dpkg -i`, then try `appstreamcli refresh --force`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream4
```

You can also test the above command before running it without making any changes to your system (so `sudo` is not required).

```
apt install --reinstall --simulate libappstream4
```