# After automatic upgrade, apt-get update cause `Error in `appstreamcli': double free or corruption`

Tags: apt

OS: 16.04

After automatic upgrade, `apt-get update` cause the following error:

```
*** Error in `appstreamcli': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001166b20 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7fe27911e7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7fe27912737a]
...
7ffc8371a000-7ffc8371c000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc8371c000-7ffc8371e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I found that this is the appstream's bug, but how can I fix it?

Comment: There is a very similar post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/library-corruption-error-during-apt-get-update) that suggests a possible way to fix this is to `sudo apt-get purge libappstream3`

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with Xubuntu 16.03 and fixed this by removing appstream package all together `apt remove appstream`.

Answer (score 3):

Just upgrade to 16.04.3 by running `apt-get upgrade`. 
After I did it, the problem had gone.

Comment: ´apt-get upgrade´ gives the original error.  ´apt-get dist-upgrade´ starts upgrading.

Comment: Or, if you can safely remove appstream package by `apt-get remove appstream`.