# Error in `appstreamcli': double free or corruption on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates

I am trying to update Xubuntu 16.04. Here is what I get on a fresh install

```
     ...$ sudo apt-get update   

*** Error in `appstreamcli': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000019f7980 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f747067c7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f747068537a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f747068953c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_component_complete+0x439)[0x7f7470a01d19]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_data_pool_update+0x44a)[0x7f7470a02f0a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_cache_builder_refresh+0x1c2)[0x7f74709f8272]
appstreamcli(ascli_refresh_cache+0x12e)[0x4049de]
appstreamcli(as_client_run+0x6fb)[0x403ceb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f7470625830]
appstreamcli(_start+0x29)[0x403519]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00408000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3670061                            /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00607000-00608000 r--p 00007000 08:11 3670061                            /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00608000-00609000 rw-p 00008000 08:11 3670061                            /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00d38000-02899000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f7464000000-7f7464021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7464021000-7f7468000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f746ad6a000-7f746ada0000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3805381                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7f746ada0000-7f746afa0000 ---p 00036000 08:11 3805381                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7f746afa0000-7f746afa5000 r--p 00036000 08:11 3805381                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7f746afa5000-7f746afa6000 rw-p 0003b000 08:11 3805381                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7f746afa6000-7f746afbf000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3805160                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7f746afbf000-7f746b1bf000 ---p 00019000 08:11 3805160                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7f746b1bf000-7f746b1c2000 r--p 00019000 08:11 3805160                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7f746b1c2000-7f746b1c3000 rw-p 0001c000 08:11 3805160                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7f746b1c3000-7f746b1ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3805156                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7f746b1ce000-7f746b3ce000 ---p 0000b000 08:11 3805156                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7f746b3ce000-7f746b3cf000 r--p 0000b000 08:11 3805156                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7f746b3cf000-7f746b3d0000 rw-p 0000c000 08:11 3805156                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7f746b3d0000-7f746bdf8000 r--p 00000000 08:11 3678003                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f746bdf8000-7f746d6ae000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3679691                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7f746d6ae000-7f746d8ad000 ---p 018b6000 08:11 3679691                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7f746d8ad000-7f746d8ae000 r--p 018b5000 08:11 3679691                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7f746d8ae000-7f746d8af000 rw-p 018b6000 08:11 3679691                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7f746d8af000-7f746d8b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1315494                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f746d8b3000-7f746dab2000 ---p 00004000 08:11 1315494                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f746dab2000-7f746dab3000 r--p 00003000 08:11 1315494                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f746dab3000-7f746dab4000 rw-p 00004000 08:11 1315494                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f746dab4000-7f746dbbc000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1310805                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f746dbbc000-7f746ddbb000 ---p 00108000 08:11 1310805                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f746ddbb000-7f746ddbc000 r--p 00107000 08:11 1310805                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f746ddbc000-7f746ddbd000 rw-p 00108000 08:11 1310805                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f746ddbd000-7f746ddde000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1315377                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f746ddde000-7f746dfdd000 ---p 00021000 08:11 1315377                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f746dfdd000-7f746dfde000 r--p 00020000 08:11 1315377                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f746dfde000-7f746dfdf000 rw-p 00021000 08:11 1315377                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f746dfdf000-7f746e15e000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3679705                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7f746e15e000-7f746e35e000 ---p 0017f000 08:11 3679705                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7f746e35e000-7f746e36e000 r--p 0017f000 08:11 3679705                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7f746e36e000-7f746e36f000 rw-p 0018f000 08:11 3679705                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7f746e36f000-7f746e373000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f746e373000-7f746e376000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1310811                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f746e376000-7f746e575000 ---p 00003000 08:11 1310811                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f746e575000-7f746e576000 r--p 00002000 08:11 1310811                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f746e576000-7f746e577000 rw-p 00003000 08:11 1310811                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f746e577000-7f746e58d000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1315348                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f746e58d000-7f746e78c000 ---p 00016000 08:11 1315348                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f746e78c000-7f746e78d000 rw-p 00015000 08:11 1315348                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f746e78d000-7f746e8ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3673614                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f746e8ff000-7f746eaff000 ---p 00172000 08:11 3673614                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f746eaff000-7f746eb09000 r--p 00172000 08:11 3673614                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f746eb09000-7f746eb0b000 rw-p 0017c000 08:11 3673614                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f746eb0b000-7f746eb0f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f746eb0f000-7f746eb3f000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3679987                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7f746eb3f000-7f746ed3e000 ---p 00030000 08:11 3679987                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7f746ed3e000-7f746ed3f000 r--p 0002f000 08:11 3679987                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7f746ed3f000-7f746ed40000 rw-p 00030000 08:11 3679987                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7f746ed40000-7f746ef34000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3680278                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7f746ef34000-7f746f134000 ---p 001f4000 08:11 3680278                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7f746f134000-7f746f13b000 r--p 001f4000 08:11 3680278                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7f746f13b000-7f746f13c000 rw-p 001fb000 08:11 3680278                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7f746f13c000-7f746f159000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3680341                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7f746f159000-7f746f359000 ---p 0001d000 08:11 3680341                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7f746f359000-7f746f35a000 r--p 0001d000 08:11 3680341                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7f746f35a000-7f746f35b000 rw-p 0001e000 08:11 3680341                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7f746f35b000-7f746f50b000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3680331                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7f746f50b000-7f746f70a000 ---p 001b0000 08:11 3680331                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7f746f70a000-7f746f712000 r--p 001af000 08:11 3680331                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7f746f712000-7f746f714000 rw-p 001b7000 08:11 3680331                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7f746f714000-7f746f715000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f746f715000-7f746f71c000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3679434                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f746f71c000-7f746f91b000 ---p 00007000 08:11 3679434                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f746f91b000-7f746f91c000 r--p 00006000 08:11 3679434                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f746f91c000-7f746f91d000 rw-p 00007000 08:11 3679434                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f746f91d000-7f746f934000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1310813                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f746f934000-7f746fb34000 ---p 00017000 08:11 1310813                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f746fb34000-7f746fb35000 r--p 00017000 08:11 1310813                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f746fb35000-7f746fb36000 rw-p 00018000 08:11 1310813                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f746fb36000-7f746fb38000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f746fb38000-7f746fb57000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1315468                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f746fb57000-7f746fd56000 ---p 0001f000 08:11 1315468                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f746fd56000-7f746fd57000 r--p 0001e000 08:11 1315468                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f746fd57000-7f746fd58000 rw-p 0001f000 08:11 1315468                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7f746fd58000-7f746fd5a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f746fd5a000-7f746fd73000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1315501                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f746fd73000-7f746ff72000 ---p 00019000 08:11 1315501                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f746ff72000-7f746ff73000 r--p 00018000 08:11 1315501                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f746ff73000-7f746ff74000 rw-p 00019000 08:11 1315501                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f746ff74000-7f746ff77000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3679555                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f746ff77000-7f7470176000 ---p 00003000 08:11 3679555                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7470176000-7f7470177000 r--p 00002000 08:11 3679555                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7470177000-7f7470178000 rw-p 00003000 08:11 3679555                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7470178000-7f7470190000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1310808                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f7470190000-7f747038f000 ---p 00018000 08:11 1310808                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f747038f000-7f7470390000 r--p 00017000 08:11 1310808                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f7470390000-7f7470391000 rw-p 00018000 08:11 1310808                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f7470391000-7f7470395000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7470395000-7f7470403000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1315439                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f7470403000-7f7470603000 ---p 0006e000 08:11 1315439                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f7470603000-7f7470604000 r--p 0006e000 08:11 1315439                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f7470604000-7f7470605000 rw-p 0006f000 08:11 1315439                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f7470605000-7f74707c5000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1310809                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f74707c5000-7f74709c5000 ---p 001c0000 08:11 1310809                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f74709c5000-7f74709c9000 r--p 001c0000 08:11 1310809                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f74709c9000-7f74709cb000 rw-p 001c4000 08:11 1310809                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f74709cb000-7f74709cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74709cf000-7f7470a1a000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3679148                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7f7470a1a000-7f7470c1a000 ---p 0004b000 08:11 3679148                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7f7470c1a000-7f7470c1b000 r--p 0004b000 08:11 3679148                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7f7470c1b000-7f7470c1c000 rw-p 0004c000 08:11 3679148                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7f7470c1c000-7f7470c6e000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3679571                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7470c6e000-7f7470e6d000 ---p 00052000 08:11 3679571                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7470e6d000-7f7470e6e000 r--p 00051000 08:11 3679571                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7470e6e000-7f7470e6f000 rw-p 00052000 08:11 3679571                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7470e6f000-7f7470fef000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 3679541                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7470fef000-7f74711ef000 ---p 00180000 08:11 3679541                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f74711ef000-7f74711f3000 r--p 00180000 08:11 3679541                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f74711f3000-7f74711f5000 rw-p 00184000 08:11 3679541                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f74711f5000-7f74711f7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f74711f7000-7f7471305000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1315352                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7471305000-7f7471505000 ---p 0010e000 08:11 1315352                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7471505000-7f7471506000 r--p 0010e000 08:11 1315352                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7471506000-7f7471507000 rw-p 0010f000 08:11 1315352                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7f7471507000-7f7471508000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7471508000-7f747152e000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 1310807                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f74716e8000-7f7471707000 r--s 00000000 08:11 3935905                    /usr/share/mime/mime.cache
7f7471707000-7f7471716000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f747172c000-7f747172d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f747172d000-7f747172e000 r--p 00025000 08:11 1310807                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f747172e000-7f747172f000 rw-p 00026000 08:11 1310807                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f747172f000-7f7471730000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffffcf63000-7ffffcf84000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffffcfbb000-7ffffcfbd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffffcfbd000-7ffffcfbf000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]    
Aborted (core dumped)    
Reading package lists... Done     
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if     /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then 
   appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'     
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Does it look like a problem of my hardware, liveUSB, ISO image, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

According to [After automatic upgrade, apt-get update cause `Error in `appstreamcli': double free or corruption`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943832/after-automatic-upgrade-apt-get-update-cause-error-in-appstreamcli-double-f)

`apt-get remove appstream` solves the problem. It worked for me as well. Ubuntu 16.04