# Apt-get core dumped!

Tags: gnome-terminal, crash, aptitude

All I did was tell it to update the package repository, and it didn't work. I've checked for bad RAM, HDD, and I've got plenty of total memory. What's wrong, or how do I fix this? Thanks!

```
joek@Jalo:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for joek:
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
*** Error in `appstreamcli': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000008c1950 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7fd421edd725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7fd421ee5f4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7fd421ee9abc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_component_complete+0x439)[0x7fd422261d19]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_data_pool_update+0x44a)[0x7fd422262f0a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.3(as_cache_builder_refresh+0x1c2)[0x7fd422258272]
appstreamcli(ascli_refresh_cache+0x12e)[0x4049de]
appstreamcli(as_client_run+0x6fb)[0x403ceb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fd421e86830]
appstreamcli(_start+0x29)[0x403519]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00408000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 264215                             /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00607000-00608000 r--p 00007000 08:01 264215                             /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00608000-00609000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 264215                             /usr/bin/appstreamcli
00845000-023e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fd418000000-7fd418021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd418021000-7fd41c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd41c634000-7fd41c63f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529418                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7fd41c63f000-7fd41c83f000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 529418                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7fd41c83f000-7fd41c840000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 529418                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7fd41c840000-7fd41c841000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 529418                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7fd41c841000-7fd41c877000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529979                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fd41c877000-7fd41ca77000 ---p 00036000 08:01 529979                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fd41ca77000-7fd41ca7c000 r--p 00036000 08:01 529979                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fd41ca7c000-7fd41ca7d000 rw-p 0003b000 08:01 529979                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fd41ca7d000-7fd41ca96000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 529422                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7fd41ca96000-7fd41cc96000 ---p 00019000 08:01 529422                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7fd41cc96000-7fd41cc99000 r--p 00019000 08:01 529422                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7fd41cc99000-7fd41cc9a000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 529422                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7fd41cc9a000-7fd41d659000 r--p 00000000 08:01 268693                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fd41d659000-7fd41ef0f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401648                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7fd41ef0f000-7fd41f10e000 ---p 018b6000 08:01 401648                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7fd41f10e000-7fd41f10f000 r--p 018b5000 08:01 401648                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7fd41f10f000-7fd41f110000 rw-p 018b6000 08:01 401648                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7fd41f110000-7fd41f114000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136767                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7fd41f114000-7fd41f313000 ---p 00004000 08:01 136767                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7fd41f313000-7fd41f314000 r--p 00003000 08:01 136767                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7fd41f314000-7fd41f315000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 136767                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7fd41f315000-7fd41f41d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136653                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fd41f41d000-7fd41f61c000 ---p 00108000 08:01 136653                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fd41f61c000-7fd41f61d000 r--p 00107000 08:01 136653                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fd41f61d000-7fd41f61e000 rw-p 00108000 08:01 136653                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7fd41f61e000-7fd41f63f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136650                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7fd41f63f000-7fd41f83e000 ---p 00021000 08:01 136650                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7fd41f83e000-7fd41f83f000 r--p 00020000 08:01 136650                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7fd41f83f000-7fd41f840000 rw-p 00021000 08:01 136650                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7fd41f840000-7fd41f9bf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401662                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7fd41f9bf000-7fd41fbbf000 ---p 0017f000 08:01 401662                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7fd41fbbf000-7fd41fbcf000 r--p 0017f000 08:01 401662                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7fd41fbcf000-7fd41fbd0000 rw-p 0018f000 08:01 401662                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7fd41fbd0000-7fd41fbd4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd41fbd4000-7fd41fbd7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136607                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7fd41fbd7000-7fd41fdd6000 ---p 00003000 08:01 136607                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7fd41fdd6000-7fd41fdd7000 r--p 00002000 08:01 136607                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7fd41fdd7000-7fd41fdd8000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 136607                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7fd41fdd8000-7fd41fdee000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136621                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fd41fdee000-7fd41ffed000 ---p 00016000 08:01 136621                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fd41ffed000-7fd41ffee000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 136621                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fd41ffee000-7fd420160000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402108                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fd420160000-7fd420360000 ---p 00172000 08:01 402108                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fd420360000-7fd42036a000 r--p 00172000 08:01 402108                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fd42036a000-7fd42036c000 rw-p 0017c000 08:01 402108                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7fd42036c000-7fd420370000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd420370000-7fd4203a0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401953                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7fd4203a0000-7fd42059f000 ---p 00030000 08:01 401953                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7fd42059f000-7fd4205a0000 r--p 0002f000 08:01 401953                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7fd4205a0000-7fd4205a1000 rw-p 00030000 08:01 401953                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9.0.1
7fd4205a1000-7fd420795000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402313                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7fd420795000-7fd420995000 ---p 001f4000 08:01 402313                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7fd420995000-7fd42099c000 r--p 001f4000 08:01 402313                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7fd42099c000-7fd42099d000 rw-p 001fb000 08:01 402313                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so.22.7.0
7fd42099d000-7fd4209ba000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402367                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7fd4209ba000-7fd420bba000 ---p 0001d000 08:01 402367                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7fd420bba000-7fd420bbb000 r--p 0001d000 08:01 402367                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7fd420bbb000-7fd420bbc000 rw-p 0001e000 08:01 402367                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7fd420bbc000-7fd420d6c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 402359                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7fd420d6c000-7fd420f6b000 ---p 001b0000 08:01 402359                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7fd420f6b000-7fd420f73000 r--p 001af000 08:01 402359                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7fd420f73000-7fd420f75000 rw-p 001b7000 08:01 402359                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7fd420f75000-7fd420f76000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd420f76000-7fd420f7d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401353                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7fd420f7d000-7fd42117c000 ---p 00007000 08:01 401353                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7fd42117c000-7fd42117d000 r--p 00006000 08:01 401353                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7fd42117d000-7fd42117e000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 401353                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7fd42117e000-7fd421195000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136735                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7fd421195000-7fd421395000 ---p 00017000 08:01 136735                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7fd421395000-7fd421396000 r--p 00017000 08:01 136735                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7fd421396000-7fd421397000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 136735                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7fd421397000-7fd421399000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd421399000-7fd4213b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136741                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7fd4213b8000-7fd4215b7000 ---p 0001f000 08:01 136741                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7fd4215b7000-7fd4215b8000 r--p 0001e000 08:01 136741                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7fd4215b8000-7fd4215b9000 rw-p 0001f000 08:01 136741                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
7fd4215b9000-7fd4215bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd4215bb000-7fd4215d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136774                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7fd4215d4000-7fd4217d3000 ---p 00019000 08:01 136774                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7fd4217d3000-7fd4217d4000 r--p 00018000 08:01 136774                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7fd4217d4000-7fd4217d5000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 136774                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7fd4217d5000-7fd4217d8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401484                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd4217d8000-7fd4219d7000 ---p 00003000 08:01 401484                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd4219d7000-7fd4219d8000 r--p 00002000 08:01 401484                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd4219d8000-7fd4219d9000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 401484                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd4219d9000-7fd4219f1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136729                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fd4219f1000-7fd421bf0000 ---p 00018000 08:01 136729                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fd421bf0000-7fd421bf1000 r--p 00017000 08:01 136729                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fd421bf1000-7fd421bf2000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 136729                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7fd421bf2000-7fd421bf6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd421bf6000-7fd421c64000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136712                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7fd421c64000-7fd421e64000 ---p 0006e000 08:01 136712                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7fd421e64000-7fd421e65000 r--p 0006e000 08:01 136712                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7fd421e65000-7fd421e66000 rw-p 0006f000 08:01 136712                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7fd421e66000-7fd422026000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136583                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fd422026000-7fd422225000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 136583                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fd422225000-7fd422229000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 136583                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fd422229000-7fd42222b000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 136583                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fd42222b000-7fd42222f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd42222f000-7fd42227a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401046                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7fd42227a000-7fd42247a000 ---p 0004b000 08:01 401046                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7fd42247a000-7fd42247b000 r--p 0004b000 08:01 401046                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7fd42247b000-7fd42247c000 rw-p 0004c000 08:01 401046                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream.so.0.9.4
7fd42247c000-7fd4224ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401508                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd4224ce000-7fd4226cd000 ---p 00052000 08:01 401508                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd4226cd000-7fd4226ce000 r--p 00051000 08:01 401508                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd4226ce000-7fd4226cf000 rw-p 00052000 08:01 401508                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd4226cf000-7fd42284f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 401470                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd42284f000-7fd422a4f000 ---p 00180000 08:01 401470                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd422a4f000-7fd422a53000 r--p 00180000 08:01 401470                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd422a53000-7fd422a55000 rw-p 00184000 08:01 401470                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd422a55000-7fd422a57000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd422a57000-7fd422b65000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136625                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd422b65000-7fd422d65000 ---p 0010e000 08:01 136625                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd422d65000-7fd422d66000 r--p 0010e000 08:01 136625                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd422d66000-7fd422d67000 rw-p 0010f000 08:01 136625                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0
7fd422d67000-7fd422d68000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd422d68000-7fd422d8e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 136555                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fd422f48000-7fd422f67000 r--s 00000000 08:01 273677                     /usr/share/mime/mime.cache
7fd422f67000-7fd422f75000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd422f89000-7fd422f8a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd422f8a000-7fd422f8b000 r--p 00000000 08:01 287431                     /usr/share/locale-langpack/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo
7fd422f8b000-7fd422f8d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fd422f8d000-7fd422f8e000 r--p 00025000 08:01 136555                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fd422f8e000-7fd422f8f000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 136555                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fd422f8f000-7fd422f90000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffca88a8000-7ffca88c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffca899b000-7ffca899d000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffca899d000-7ffca899f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]Aborted (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
joek@Jalo:~$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         988312      496332       58536      240968      433444      211512
Swap:       4194300       81220     4113080
joek@Jalo:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How to fix", try

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream3
```

or even

```
sudo apt-get purge libappstream3
```

Taken from [Library corruption error during apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/library-corruption-error-during-apt-get-update)