# 18.04 to 18.10 upgrade failure

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I have a DELL laptop and I have upgraded Ubuntu on this machine without issue until now. I have tried several times to upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10 and I've tried some of the recommendations on this site to try and get it installed, but it always  fails. I tried from Terminal and got more detail on the attempted upgrade when it failed which I have pasted below. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or could do to fix this? Thanks.

```
do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,255 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,256 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'cosmic.tar.gz' against 'cosmic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'cosmic.tar.gz'
[sudo] password for steve: 

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Ign dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
Hit ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Get:1 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]             
Get:2 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]         
Hit ppa.launchpad.net/klaus-vormweg/pan/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Get:3 ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.8 kB]    
Hit ppa.launchpad.net/ozmartian/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Get:4 ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [43.6 kB]
Get:5 ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [43.6 kB]
Fetched 109 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   

(appstreamcli:15338): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:05:45.946: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:15338): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:05:45.947: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:15338): GLib-ERROR **: 14:05:45.947: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                       
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

(appstreamcli:15614): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:06:55.537: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:15614): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:06:55.538: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:15614): GLib-ERROR **: 14:06:55.538: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                       
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

(appstreamcli:15829): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:07:05.466: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:15829): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:07:05.466: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:15829): GLib-ERROR **: 14:07:05.466: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
Hit http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                       
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

(appstreamcli:16059): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:07:13.383: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:16059): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:07:13.383: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:16059): GLib-ERROR **: 14:07:13.383: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

E:Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if 
/usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; 
then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi', E:Sub-process 
returned an error code 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Tried the update through the Distribution Upgrade popup which appeared onscreen. It also failed with the following message:

Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

E:Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi', E:Sub-process returned an error code.

I'm just thinking - if a couple of people have mentioned my internet connection was running, which it was, or if I was using a proxy, which I'm not and the latest try at upgrade showed that there may be a connection issue, could the laptopwifi adapter be getting switched off as it tries to update?

Comment: are you certain your internet connection was running?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yep, internet is up and running each time I try. Just tried again this morning with same result.

Comment: hi, are you using a proxy? because if you read the return, it clearly  shows it has to do with your internet connection e.g. `Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s) `, please also tell us, what command you were running.

Comment: What recommendations did you try? Are you using a proxy, VPN, or corporate/university network? Please [edit] to add.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Problem executing scripts APT Update::Post-Invoke-Success error during apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/e-problem-executing-scripts-apt-updatepost-invoke-success-error-during-apt-ge)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (on an acer notebook) when trying

```
    sudo do-release-upgrade
```

What then worked without errors was

```
    sudo su -
    apt dist-upgrade
    do-release-upgrade
```