# how to fix missing libappstream.so.4 error

Tags: apt, 18.04, update-manager

I can't update or install new software in my Ubuntu 18.04 system after upgrading it from 16.04.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

returns ...

```
Hit:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]   
Get:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB] 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]    
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Sources [283 kB]
Get:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Sources [319 kB] 
Get:7 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [949 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Sources [170 kB]
Get:9 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [684 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Sources [150 kB] 
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [725 kB]
Get:12 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [304 kB]
Get:13 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1076 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [473 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42,6 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [667 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [622 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [222 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42,1 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2464 B]
Get:21 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [1017 kB]
Get:22 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [273 kB]
Get:23 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2468 B]
Get:24 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7968 B]
Fetched 8282 kB in 3s (2743 kB/s)                              
appstreamcli: error while loading shared libraries: libappstream.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

i tried alot of things, several times over the past months, like installing these things manually, but ...

```
sudo apt install libappstream4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libappstream4 : Depends: libstemmer0d (>= 0+svn527) but it is not going to be installed
 libdbus-1-dev : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (= 2.36.11-2) but 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
                        Depends: libpng-dev (>= 1.6)
                        Depends: libpng-dev (< 1.7)
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings : Depends: libproxy1v5 (= 0.4.15-1) but 0.4.11-5ubuntu1 is to be installed
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.6-1~) but 3.5.1-3 is to be installed
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.6-1~) but 3.5.1-3 is to be installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.22) but 237-3ubuntu10.29 is to be installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu21.22) but 237-3ubuntu10.29 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

even ....

```
apt-get -f install
```

wont solve my problem

nor

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt-get update -y
```

https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libappstream4

i upgraded from 16.0x to 18.04 some time ago via terminal commands, all good,, i didn't install a lot of software, pretty much nothing actually, except updating Apache and PHP.  Even the GNOME Shell GUI fails.

how to fix?

Comment: try using synaptic to detect and repair broken packages

Comment: i tried, "sudo apt-get install synaptic" but it's impossible to install anything, via terminal nor via ubunto software app, i download the *.deb file. it keeps complaining about "libappstream4" and etc. how is the other app called?

Comment: using "dpkg -l" i have "libappstream3:amd64                         0.9.4-1ubuntu4             amd64" installed instead of libappstream4, how to fix?

Comment: sudo dpkg -i /tmp/mozilla_doody0/appstream_0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.2_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 257166 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../appstream_0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking appstream (0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.2) over (0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of appstream:
 appstream depends on libappstream4 (>= 0.10.2); however:
  Package libappstream4 is not installed.

<https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-backports/appstream>

Comment: why don't you consider a new installation ? backup your data and go to 20.04. I would, if I were in your place

Comment: that's what i did in the end, because on reboot i couldn't log in into my computer, which i also tried to solve, but ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Problem executing scripts APT Update::Post-Invoke-Success error during apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/e-problem-executing-scripts-apt-updatepost-invoke-success-error-during-apt-ge)