# APT update error from fwupd.xml

Tags: apt

Ubuntu 16.04

I'm getting this `apt update` error:

```
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: 
Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
```

I have previously run:

```
sudo apt install appstream/xenial-backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

The above error still exists.

Comment: `appstream` has been known to mess up the `fwupd.xml` file...Do you have any custom data in it? if not, you can just delete it and try to update. Maybe you can even see what the error is, manually correct it, and notify the developer at [github](https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how I can fix "AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors."?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854168/how-i-can-fix-appstream-cache-update-completed-but-some-metadata-was-ignored-d)

Comment: answers in https://askubuntu.com/questions/854168/how-i-can-fix-appstream-cache-update-completed-but-some-metadata-was-ignored-d have not worked. Deleting fwupd.xml did work.

Comment: I suggest you add this finding either as an answer to the proposed duplicate, or as an answer to this question here (your own) below, if you do not consider it to be the same problem. I voted to leave open in the meantime

Comment: Today there was a new /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml causing the same issue, so the issue is not solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04: appstreamcli error while get-update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894519/ubuntu-16-04-appstreamcli-error-while-get-update)

Comment: There's this about  [replacing with libappstream-glib8 for xenial with libappstream-glib8 for bionic](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395753&p=13784553#post13784553) however this is my main machine and not prepared to experiment.

Answer (score 5):

Following the comments, what solved this for me was:

```
# rm /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
# appstreamcli refresh --force
AppStream cache update completed successfully.
# apt update
```

Everything seems fine now.

---

Should also add that I have version `0.10.6` installed from `xenial/back-ports`.

Comment: Hope you're more lucky than me. Tried that a few weeks ago, then it *appeared* to be fixed, but the problem was back after a few days.

Comment: @RingØ In that case, fingers crossed but so far so good

Comment: Unfortunately, after a shutdown and restart a few hours later the problem is back.

Comment: @RingØ What version do you have? Mine is `AppStream CLI tool version: 0.10.6`

Comment: The same on ubuntu 16.04 fully patched. Did you do a cold shutdown, then restart after some time, and `apt update`?

Comment: @RingØ I've simply restarted gnome-shell a number of times, but let me try full restart and see if it returns

Comment: Restarted and still no problems after running `apt update`. I also ran `appstreamcli refresh --force`, and once again I got the same success message. If it helps I am running kernel version 4.15 (`uname -r`)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the error described in your question is caused by a typo in `/var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml`.

**My fix procedure:**

1. Open this file on the terminal with command `sudo gedit /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml`. I am using the `gedit` text editor here. You can use any text editor that you are comfortable with.
2. Goto line 265 which says `<checksum filename="Firmware_SF30&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat" target="content" type="sha1">3ef2bdee8aca2a45b9f53b4d4cce9722523f57f8</checksum>`. 
   All I did to fix the error was to correct the typo `SF30&SN30` to `SF30&amp;SN30`. That is the symbol `&` should be changed to `&amp;`.
3. Finally, save the file and exit.

To check if successful, run on terminal `sudo apt update`. The error should not be there. But if it was still there, I ran the command `appstreamcli refresh --force` and then `sudo apt update`. By this stage, I no longer encountered the error during the same login session.

**Additional notes:**

1. Sometimes, Ubuntu does notify me of new packages that are available
   for installation and will ask me for permission to install these new
   packages. After installing these new packages, I have encountered
   the same error messages in your question during `sudo apt update`.
   To avoid the error, I just redo the procedure as mentioned above.
   Hope the developers can quickly fix this bug.
2. I have come across advice to remove files `fwupd.xml` and
   `50appstream`. However, I noticed that these files contained
   instructions to serve certain purposes. Hence, my fix procedure did
   not remove those files. If you want to remove them, I suggest you
   make a backup of them first.

Answer (score 1):

After experiencing the same update issues I built a short-term solution that helps to mend the situation until developers adjust the syntax errors in the problematic XML file.

**Proposed Short-Term Solution: bugfix.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
# bugfix.sh
#
# DESCRIPTION
#   Temporary fix for Ubuntu firmware update issues
#   Created by h8rt3rmin8r on 20180804
#
# BUG INFORMATION 
#   File location:  /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
#   Line number:    265

SRC_STRING=$(sudo cat /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml)
OLD_SUBSTRING='Firmware_SF30&SN30_Pro_V1'
NEW_SUBSTRING='Firmware_SF30&amp;SN30_Pro_V1'

touch /dev/shm/bugfix.xml
echo ${SRC_STRING/$OLD_SUBSTRING/$NEW_SUBSTRING} > /dev/shm/bugfix.xml

sudo mv /dev/shm/bugfix.xml /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
```

**Instructions On Using bugfix.sh:**

To run bugfix.sh, simply copy the code above into a new file (using a text editor like gedit) and save that file as "bugfix.sh" in a convenient location.

While located in the same directory as the bugfix.sh script, enable script execution with the following command: `sudo chmod +x bugfix.sh`

Run the bugfix script with the command: `./bugfix.sh`

**Additional Notes:**

Running this script will temporarily solve the problem at hand. If the error in question pops up again at a later date then just run the script again.

For easy access you could even store this script in `/usr/local/bin` so you can call it directly from the terminal with `bugfix.sh`. Then, as long as the bug is around, you can call `bugfix.sh` before running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade`.