# Installing driver

Tags: binary, syntax

I've been trying to install some intel drivers, but I get an error message. This is the text:

```
alberto@alberto-Inspiron-5558:~$ cd Desktop
alberto@alberto-Inspiron-5558:~/Desktop$ chmod a+x kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin
alberto@alberto-Inspiron-5558:~/Desktop$ sudo ./kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin 
./kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin: 1: ./kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
  alberto@alberto-Inspiron-5558:~$ lsb_release -d 
  Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
  alberto@alberto-Inspiron-5558:~$ sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version 
  Version: 1.157.20
```

Comment: What is `kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin` supposed to be? `file kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin` Is it supposed to be a shell script? Is it missing the shebang line? `head -n 1 kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin`. Try `bash ./ kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin`

Comment: In my installation of Ubuntu 18.04, it is already installed in `/lib/firmware/i915` What Ubuntu version are you running? `lsb_release -d` What is the result of: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version` Please edit your question to add these results. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I've added the results.

Comment: @waltinator Actually, I don't know, I was doing I saw in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could download the file and copy it to `/lib/firmware`, I suggest that you instead upgrade the linux-firmware package. From the terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173_all.deb
```

Notice that you have version 1.157 and this is the much newer 1.173. Install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Check to see that it's installed:

```
ls /lib/firmware/i915
```

Reboot.

Comment: I just did that but now when I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this `AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml`

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053869/apt-update-error-from-fwupd-xml

Comment: This worked https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/library-corruption-error-during-apt-get-update