# Why has a lot of software disappeared from Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, software-center

For example there is no VirtualBox, Texmaker, LyX, calibre, Redshift.

I have ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`. I have not used BleachBit. The only thing wrong in my computer seems to be that I often get an error message like this one when I run `sudo apt update`:

```
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

, which I would also like to fix by the way.

Things I tried that did not help:

As advised in [Library corruption error during apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/library-corruption-error-during-apt-get-update), I ran `sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream3` and then `sudo apt purge libappstream3`, and then I also restarted my computer. Then I ran `sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream3` again `sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream4` and I restarted the computer again.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Check that Software Center is even installed with `dpkg -l`. If it's shown then remove and purge it. Then `sudo apt-get autoremove`, then reinstall: `sudo apt install software-center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be enough to just wait for a fix to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1780442) to be released.

In the meantime here is a temporary solution:

Replace `&` with `&amp;` in line 265 in `/var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1053018/309223).  Reboot.

This solution is temporary because the file reverts to the original 'just &'-containing version after some time.

This is to fix all problems in my question.